# Is there a way to arrange rows with same values (group them) one below other in a Netsuite Saved Search?

Tags: oracle, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want to display all the rows with same value together in a Netsuite Saved Search.
For example,

If user selects some Name, lets say XYZ, then all the rows with name = XYZ should be displayed together i.e. one below another. This continues for all the names present in the Saved Search.

```
Name Age 
XYZ  21
XYZ  16
PQR  18  
PQR  12
RST  28
```

Also I need to initiate such a grouping using script. I am using Suitescript 2.0 and I am displaying data in a Suitelet. Is there any way to achieve this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply just want to sort results based on a specific column then this is what you can do:

In NetSuite > Saved Search: Edit Saved Search > Results (subtab) > set Sort By field = *column name*.
[image]
In SuiteScript 2.0: Where you are adding columns, you can use **sort** property in search.createColumn() api like this:

search.createColumn({
name: 'salesrep',
sort: search.Sort.ASC
})

Comment: Thank You. I actually need to sort it out based on conditions. If Condition 1 satisfies, I need to sort it based on 3 columns. But if Condition 2 is satisfied, I need only 2 columns. So is there a way to achieve this? Possibly passing something through script?

Comment: I don't think you can manipulate what is seen in the UI via script for a Saved Search.  However you (1) can create a Portlet script type to run the search, evaluate your logic, then sort and display the content to the user.  Or (2) a button (User Event script) or URL (Suitelet script) that one could trigger before opening the search.  The script triggered could load the search, evaluate your logic, set the sorting, etc. Depending on script type you can redirect the user to the saved search or just instruct them to open it...

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet in SuiteScript 1.0 which shows the similar requirement that you have.Here is the explaination for the same
(1) Create a field of type 'select' in your Suitelet script (here : 'custpage_vendors')
(2) Filtering will happen on the basis of the above mentioned field : Vendor
(3) Once user selects any value on the Suitelet field : Vendor then group the results by that vendor
(4) In your case, you need to also need to add conditions based on which you want to group
Eg if (condition1 == true)
{
var arrColumns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_event_vendor', null, 'group')];
}
else if(condition2 == true)
{
var arrColumns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('anotherfieldid', null, 'group')];
}

// Add Type field with values from  Event Type list
var fldType = form.addField('custpage_type', 'select', 'Type', stEVentTypeCustomRecordId).setMandatory(true);

```
// Add Vendor field with values including Vendors
var fldVendor = form.addField('custpage_vendors', 'select', 'Vendors'); 
var arrColumns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_event_vendor', null, 'group')];
var arrVendorsSearch = nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_events', null, null, arrColumns);
if (arrVendorsSearch != null)
{
    fldVendor.addSelectOption('', '');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrVendorsSearch.length; i++)
    {
        fldVendor.addSelectOption(arrVendorsSearch[i].getValue('custrecord_event_vendor', null, 'group'), arrVendorsSearch[i].getText('custrecord_event_vendor', null, 'group'));
    }       
}
```

Please let me know if this works!